# Save jQuery Droppable shopping list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I am searching for a few days to find an example for saving in a sql table a shopping list made using jQuery.
The code is here: [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart)

What I need is an example (a starting point) showing how to save in a table (insert record) all the products dropped in the "shopping cart" pressing a "Save" button.

I tried using something like:

> input type = "hidden" id="item id"

but I can save only one item.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id as selector.

for exa.

```
$(".YourClass").prop('selected')
```

i dont have your proper code, otherwise i can give you more explanation.

still, you have any query, just comment it.